# Is the situation of "key==this" possible?

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm reading the Hashtable's code. and I am confused about the `toString()` method, the code is like this :

```
public synchronized String toString() 
{
    int max = size() - 1;
    if (max == -1)
       return "{}";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> it = entrySet().iterator();
    sb.append('{');

    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        Map.Entry<K,V> e = it.next();
        K key = e.getKey();
        V value = e.getValue();

        // Is "key == this" possible ? What the "this" stands for ?
        sb.append(key   == this ? "(this Map)" : key.toString());
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(value == this ? "(this Map)" : value.toString());

        if (i == max)
            return sb.append('}').toString();

        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
```

So,if the code doesn't check whether "key equals this" or not, maybe the toString() method can be endless loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is possible:

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
table.put(table, table);
System.out.println("table = " + table);
```

outputs:

```
table = {(this Map)=(this Map)}
```

Note however that the behaviour of such a map could be surprising (as its hashcode and equals will change). For example, in the example below, you can't remove the map from itself once you add another entry:

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
table.put(table, table);
System.out.println("table = " + table);
table.put("abc", "def");
System.out.println("table = " + table);
table.remove(table); //does not work as expected !!!
System.out.println("table = " + table);
```

outputs:

```
table = {(this Map)=(this Map)}
table = {abc=def, (this Map)=(this Map)}
table = {abc=def, (this Map)=(this Map)}
```

Comment: So,if the code doesn't check whether "key equals this" or not, maybe the toString() method can be endless loop?

Answer (score 1):

This is so that if you put the `HashTable` into itself you don't get an infinite loop. Consider:

```
final Map map = new Hashtable();
map.put(map, "test");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Is "key == this" possible ? What the "this" stands for ?
```

'this keyword' refers to the current instance of the object. "key == this" checks if key refers to the current insatnce of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. This

```
HashTable<Object, Object> maptest = new HashTable<Object, Object>();
mapTest.put(mapTest, 1);
```

would have `key == this` return `true`

Answer (score 0):

There is a  possibility that keeping a `map` as key in same `map`.

```
HashMap<Object, Object> selfmap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
selfmap.put(selfmap, selfmap);
```

Comment: That will probably bring about infinite recursion when you attempt to call hashCode or toString.

Answer (score 0):

if the `key` and `this` object (HashTable as you say) reference equals then the condition `key == this` is `true`