# When I new a Hashtable, why the put method is invocated?

Tags: java, hashtable

I am reading the code of `Hashtable` and am confused  and have some questions.
I coded like this:

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
table.put(table, 1);
int code = table.hashCode();
```

I have two questions:

1. When I invoke the `hashCode` method just like the third line code, why isn't it an endless loop? I think it is an endless loop.
2. When I debug this code, I found that code `new Hashtable()` will cause the invocation of `put` method, why?

Comment: Can you describe why you think the third line should be an infinite loop?  Every object in Java has a hashCode that can be used, e.g., for determining where in hash table the object should be placed.  Hash tables, like every other object, can be put into a hash table, and need hash codes too.  Please elaborate on how you're seeing `new Hashtable()` call `put`.  This would be surprising, and it probably more likely a confusion about what the debugger is actually showing.  Perhaps you're see the statement immediately _after_ the `new Hashtable()`, which is a call to `put`?

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: Because the `hashCode` of a `Hashtable` is a function of the `hashCode`s of the elements in the `Hashtable`. You can see this by referring to the [documentation](http://bit.ly/19j7i8E) for `Map.hashCode`. If the `Hashtable` is itself an element of the `Hashtable`, well, that's why the OP's questions is *not* a bad question.

Comment: When I debug the code, it is not an endless loop. when the key(hashtable)'s hashcode is invocated, it returned 0, so it is not an endless loop, but this make no sense.

Comment: @Jason I didn't say it was a bad question (indeed, it's not), but without citing the documentation that says that the hashcode is a function of the hashcodes of the table's keys, it's not immediately obvious why someone would expect infinite recursion.

Comment: @user2331313: It makes perfect sense if there's logic in `Hashtable.hashCode` to detect this wacky situation and prevent it from causing an infinite loop. In Open JDK the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java#792) is available, and it shows returning zero in the case that `Hashtable.hashCode` is invoked, while *in the middle of a `Hashtable.hashCode` invocation for exactly the same instance*.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: I didn't say that you said it's a bad question (you didn't say that I said that you said it's a bad question, I didn't say that you said that I said that you said it's a bad question, ..., `java.lang.StackOverflowError`).

Comment: Sée also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835592/is-the-situation-of-key-this-possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. According to [the OpenJDK source I'm reading](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java#792), there's a guard written specifically to guard against the case where a Hashtable contains itself.
2. I don't see any reference to `put` within the constructor. Do you have a trace you could post in your answer?

Comment: Jeff: Is that Sun's implementation? Oracle's doesn't have it.

Comment: I wonder if HashMap has the same guard (or falls into infinity). From the comment in the code this seems to be a specific work-around for legacy code.

Comment: @Thilo Looks like `AbstractMap.hashCode` iterates and calls `hashCode` on the entries, and I'm not seeing any such guard in [`HashMap.Entry.hashCode`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.Entry.hashCode%28%29).

Comment: If I use HashMap instead of Hashtable ,it will go to an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

First off, use a hashmap as it's better in many cases.

Second, this uses Oracle's [implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Hashtable.java.html).

It's not an infinite loop. `HashTable.hashCode(` simply iterates through the map's elements *once*. Not infinitely. Unless the table contains itself, where in the [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Hashtable.java.html) I found it is indeed very hacky but does prevent the recursion. In that case it skips calculating its own hash code returning 0.

1. Looking at the source, no `put(` is called. Only the next line calls `Put`.

Comment: But if the first element is the table itself, it does look like endless recursion.

Comment: I assume that by "endless loop", user2331313 means infinite *recursion*, not infinite *iteration*. (Since the table's hash-code depends on the hash-codes of all of its keys, including itself . . .)

Comment: When I debug the code, it is not an endless loop. when the key(hashtable)'s hashcode is invocated, it returned 0, so it is not an endless loop, but this make no sense.